# How do I find a word in a string using RegEx and C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I cannot seem to find solution to find a certain word from a string.

Example:
Searching: Hi

From: Laughing

using `String.Contains` or `Regex.IsMatch` returning true value. I need something to find inside string but not part of word.

Testing using `String.Contains()` or `Regex.ISMatch()`

```
("Hi", "Laughing") return true  //It should return false
```

What I would like returned is this:

```
("Hi","Hi!") or ("Say Hi!") //this is what i want exactly
```

[Second test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiqO1.png)

Comment: Why do you provide us the code you are trying to get to work, and the expected output, and the output you are getting. A bit difficult based on what you have provided.

Comment: So you're searching for `"Hi"` - `"laughing"` should not match, but `"Say hi!"` should match? If so, `Regex.IsMatch` could be used with the right pattern, it shouldn't be hard to find a tutorial/example.

Comment: `\bhi\b`. \b denotes a [Word Boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Regex.IsMatch still return true for laughing

Comment: Look at this regex: https://regex101.com/r/XKl0AP/1 it gives you what you want.

Comment: ow yeah using \b, it works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Regex.IsMatch maybe not still stuck returning another false?
Image in second test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var pattern = @"\bHi\b";
    var phrase = "Hi, John!";
    var phrase2 = "Hello Philip!";
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(phrase, pattern));
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(phrase2, pattern));
```

Comment: ow yeah works now for boath string Thanks! seems missing @